# How to masking the last number in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, int, masking

How to mask the last string using swift, I have made the code as below. but the code only shows the last number, my expectation is that the code displays the first 5 digits

here my code:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var masked: String {
        return String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count-5)) + suffix(5)
    } }

var name = "0123456789"

print(name.masked)
```

I get output: •••••56789

but my expectations: 01234•••••

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a prefix instead of a suffix

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var masked: String {
        return prefix(5) + String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count-5))
    } 
}
```

You could also create a function instead for parameterizing the number of digits and direction (or even the mask character)

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func masked(_ n: Int = 5, reversed: Bool = false) -> String {
        let mask = String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count-n))
        return reversed ? mask + suffix(n) : prefix(n) + mask
    } 
}

var name = "0123456789"

print(name.masked(5)) 
// 01234•••••

print(name.masked(5, reversed: true)) 
// •••••56789
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a case of wanting to mask an email address. here's the code

```
func maskingEmail(email: String) -> String {
    let emailComponents = email.components(separatedBy: "@")
    let emailDomainComponents = emailComponents[1].components(separatedBy: ".")
    let maskedEmailName = String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, emailComponents[0].count-3)) + emailComponents[0].suffix(3)
    let maskedEmailProvider = String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, emailDomainComponents[0].count-3)) + emailDomainComponents[0].suffix(3)
    let emailDomain = emailDomainComponents[1]
    return "\(maskedEmailName)@\(maskedEmailProvider).\(emailDomain)"
}

// The Output
print(maskingEmail(email: "pr1vaterelay@gmail.com")) // •••••••••lay@••ail.com
print(maskingEmail(email: "private_relay@bk.ru")) // ••••••••••lay@bk.ru
print(maskingEmail(email: "private.relay@protonmail.com")) // ••••••••••lay@•••••••ail.com
```