# How to masking textfield in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, textfield, masking

I want masking email in textfield.text, but I only get the value in the middle. I want to get the value from the middle to @ gmail.com like example below.

ex:

1. let var = 12345678@gmail.com

output = ****5678@gmail.com

2. let var = 123456789@gmail.com

output = ****56789@gmail.com

```
    let email = "123456789@gmail.com"

    let components = email.components(separatedBy: "@")

    let result = hideMidChars(components.first!) + "@" + components.last!

    print(result)
```

output I get: ****5****@gmail.com

my expectations: ****56789@gmail.com

Comment: its clear that issue with function `hideMidChars`. Is it your own function?

Comment: Why doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279663/how-to-masking-the-last-number-in-swift) work for you?

Comment: but in this case i only masking from the beginning of the text to @gmail and devide by 2.
example i have int with 8 number:
12345678@gmail.com
masking only ****45678@gmail.com
how about i have 10 number:
1234567890@gmail.com
masking only *****67890@gmail.com

i get data from Api,
in that link we can add position masking from.

how about from json, data is random. so i can't use that

Comment: you may use same answer from your own question as @JoakimDanielson indicated. Change hardcoded 5 to half of the length of your string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func hide(email: String) -> String {

    let parts = email.split(separator: "@")
    if parts.count < 2 {
        return email
    }
    let name = parts[0]
    let appendix = parts[1]
    let lenght = name.count
    if lenght == 1 {
        return "*@\(appendix)"
    }
    let semiLenght = lenght / 2

    var suffixSemiLenght = semiLenght
    if (lenght % 2 == 1) {
        suffixSemiLenght += 1
    }

    let prefix = String(repeating: "*", count: semiLenght)
    let lastPart = String(name.suffix(suffixSemiLenght))

    let result = "\(prefix)\(lastPart)@\(appendix)"
    return result
}
let email = "123456789@gmail.com"
let result = hide(email: email)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try extending the string protocol and declare a variable which returns an .init(repeating: ,count):

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var masked: String {
        return String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count - count/2)) + suffix(count/2)
    }
}
```

usage as follows:

```
let email = "123456789@gmail.com"

print(email.masked)   //"••••••••••gmail.com"
```

if you want a part of the email showing just manipulate the suffix(count - 3) as follows:

```
return String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count - count/2)) + suffix(count/2)
```